# Correct way to import an RSS feed and display it in a view?

Tags: 7, feeds, social-network

I have an rss feed (facebook) (can also be output as a json). I want to import the RSS feed and have it display using a view.

I already have the Feeds module installed and the Feeds: Facebook Parser installed. I think I have everything I need but I can't figure out how put it together. Seems like this is a common need just not sure how to put the pieces together to make it happen.

Answer (score 5):

The proper way to import an RSS feed and have its data displayed in a view is by creating nodes from the feed data. This is what the Feeds module accomplishes.

You will need to define two content types: one to be used by the feed importer (ex. "Facebook Feed Importer") and one for the feed items themselves (ex. "Facebook Feed Item"). In the feeds importer:

- Under Basic settings, attach the feed to the Facebook Feed Importer content type.
- Set the node processor bundle to Facebook Feed Item.
- Map the fields.

See [this tutorial](https://drupal.org/node/638804) for more details in setting up the importer. If you have troubles using the Feeds: Facebook Parser, give the [Feeds JSONPath Parser](https://drupal.org/project/feeds_jsonpath_parser) a try.

Once you have everything configured correctly, make a new Facebook Feed Importer node, enter in the feed URL, and save the node. View this node and click import. The RSS data should be imported as Facebook Feed Item nodes. If you get errors, or 0 nodes created, you probably have an issue with your mappings or importer configuration.

By importing the feed data into your website as nodes you have more flexibility in how you can display this information to the user. Instead of having one large string of data for a feed item, you have a node containing fields for each part of the feed item which can then be customized in your views or anywhere else on your site however is required.