# External RSS Feed in View

Tags: 7, feeds

I am looking for a module or way to use an external RSS feed in a view. I know this was easily done in Drupal 6, but I can't seem to find much on Drupal 7.

I am trying to use Views RSS, but there is very limited documentation.

Comment: You might want to check out: http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/88725/correct-way-to-import-an-rss-feed-and-display-it-in-a-view?rq=1

Comment: Do you want to consume an RSS feed or create one ?

Comment: @user1081275 Consume one

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The simplest method is to use the Aggregator module included in core.

1. Enable the 'aggregator' module in core
2. Add your RSS feed in Configuration > Web services > Feed aggregator
3. On the same page, click 'update items' for your feed to retrieve the RSS feed and parse the items
4. Create a view that will show 'Aggregator items'
5. (Optional step for multiple feeds) Add a filter criteria for 'Aggregator feed: Title' to only show items from the specified feed

To do more advanced functionality you will need to use the [Feeds](https://www.drupal.org/project/feeds) module from contrib. That module will parse the fields from a feed into content nodes.

Comment: The problem I'm running into right now is that I need the block to accept a context from the panel. Not seeing any way to do that.. any ideas?

Comment: You might want to open a new question and provide more details about this problem.

Comment: True. Just realized I had left that portion out, thanks man.

Answer (score 0):

One of the sites I manage takes an RSS feed from a Ruby site and displays the content on our Drupal site via Views. To do this we use Feeds, which imports the RSS and then they are just normal nodes you can use in the view.