# How to dynamically consume external RSS feed and display content Drupal 7 with feeds module?

Tags: feeds

Is it possible to consume an external RSS feed with the feeds module - without turning the content into nodes - and display it in a view? I attempted to do this using the aggregator module as described here: [External RSS Feed in View](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/138660/external-rss-feed-in-view) and it looked great at first, but then I discovered this bug where the aggregator does not update. https://www.drupal.org/node/2344795. I am now trying to do the same thing with the feeds module, but I don't see a way to have it not create nodes out of the data. I just want it to be dynamic and not create content nodes on my site. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have sucessfully used [Views XML Backend](https://www.drupal.org/project/views_xml_backend) in situations like this.

Comment: Worked like a charm. Thanks so much. I had not heard of that module before.